# Substituting color with vertex attributes

Tags: opengl

I have a large set of vertices and currently use `glColorPointer` to specify their color. The problem is, that `glColorPointer` only accepts a size of 3 or 4 as its first parameter but the value of R, G and B for each vertex is identical.

Of course, I could use `glVertexAttribPointer` to specify each color value as an attribute of size one and duplicate it in a shader, but I'm looking for a way to do this in the fixed function pipeline.
Calling `glColor1*` is unfortunately out of the question given the amount of vertices (Yes, I tried it).

Any creative solution that squeezes the value into something else is also OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think without shaders this won't be possible since, well, `glColorPointer` only accepts a size of 3 or 4, like you already found out (there should also be no `glColor1`, only `glColor3` and `glColor4`).

You might trick `glColorPointer` to use your tightly packed array by specifying a size of 3 but a stride of 1 (ubyte) or 4 (float). But this will give you a color of `(Ri, Ri+1, Ri+2)` for vertex `i` and there is no way to adjust it to `(Ri, Ri, Ri)`, since the color matrix is not applied to per-vertex colors but only to pixel images.

So without shaders you don't have much creativity left. What you could do is use a 1D texture of size 256, which contains all the grey colors from (0, 0, 0) to (255, 255, 255) in order. Then you can just use your per-vertex color as 1D texture coordinate into that texture. But I'm not sure if that would really buy you anything in either space or time.

The easy and straightforward way is to use vertex attributes and a shader to implement the unpacking of the attribute into the fragment color. This takes just a few lines of shader code and should be the preferred solution. The real difficulty here is the artificial restriction, not the problem space itself. Such cases should be handled by lifting the restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In the end I just hacked a `const char*` shader in there and went went with a single float attribute per vertex that I mapped into a color. Artificially restricting myself was the mistake in the first place.

Comment: @pmr Since you explicitly said that you know how to do it with a shader but didn't want to, I didn't elaborate more on this topic. It could have just been that this restriction is not artificial but real (old hardware or whatever). Since the question asked explicitly for a no-shader solution, the answer could also have been accepted without editing, but thanks for accepting anyway. The edit reflects my thoughts anyway.

Comment: I made up that constraint in the pursuit of making the program "simple". That assumption was wrong to begin with hence I ended up calling the constraint artificial. The real answer was the realization of that and your post helped me to see that. Thus it is the answer that should be accepted. It's meta-sunday over here.

Comment: @pmr No matter if the restriction is made-up or real, it is a restriction that restricts the answers. So a question respecting that restriction is perfectly valid. An answer that only said "use a shader, man" (without giving any answer to the no-shader question, of course) would in turn be invalid. No matter if you realized the question was wrong, the answer still needs to fit the question. It would be different hadn't you explicitly mentioned the need for a no-shader solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the color information in an 1D texture (with only one channel), then you can use a vertex shader which reads the proper color based on the `gl_vertexID`.

Comment: Sorry, no shaders. As mentioned in the question. The limitation is stupid, I know. Don't ask.